# Build an object consisting of the name/value pairs of cells in an HTML table row in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, html-table

I'm brand new to JS so bear with me; I'm not even sure if I'm searching for the answer the right way, but I haven't been able to get it working after hours of googling and tinkering.

I have an HTML table and the user clicks on a row.  I can get the clicked element like this:

```
var elem = document.elementFromPoint(e.clientX, e.clientY);
```

I can also get the row like this:

```
var tr = elem.closest("tr");
```

Now I want to build an array of name/value pairs from the cells where the name is the data field name and the value is the cell's inner text, so I do this:

```
var set = []; 

$.each(tr.cells, function(cell) { 
    set.push({name : cell.dataset.field, value : cell.innerText}); 
});
```

But I'm getting this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: **Cannot read property 'field' of undefined**
>   at HTMLTableCellElement. (:1:80)
>   at Function.each (jquery.min.js:2)
>   at :1:17

Here is what this looks like in the Chrome dev tools console:

[image]

Here's a watch on `tr` where the highlighted portion shows the `field` I'm looking for.

[image]

I'm pretty sure I can turn the array of name/value pairs into an object after I get it, e.g. with `JSON.parse()` or something.

---

So what is wrong with my code or my approach?  Is there a more-concise or more-efficient way to do what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Can you post your HTML table here too. I'll try reproducing it locally.

Comment: Try `console.log(cell)` and `console.log(cell.dataset)` inside the loop...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are just missing the required parameter ordering for `$.each()` (index is the first parameter and then the element). So you just need to change it to something like:

```
$.each(tr.cells, function(index, elem) {
  set.push({
    name: elem.dataset.field,
    value: elem.innerText
  });
});
```

Comment: Brilliant!  So why is the error complaining about the wrong thing then?

Comment: @rory.ap - because `cell` in your initial attempt is an integer (because it references the index value), so `cell.dataset` is undefined because the integer doesn't have any properties. Not a real helpful error in this case but accurate I think.